# draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

**Python Version:** 3.4

**PyGame?:** Yes

Alright so I'm using Python and PyGame aswell as following a tutorial on youtube since I'm new to programming.

I've tried multiple things like adding a_block to the parameters aswell with my game_display but then it says that my object Block has no sprite thing called.
I've also tried searching this up multiple times but I haven't found anything useful yet. The tutorial I believe was done in Python 2.

**Block Class:**

```
# Creates a class for our block
class Block (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Creates an object
    def __init__(self,colour = blue,width = 64,height = 64):

        super(Block,self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((width,height))
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def set_position(self,x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

**Part of my Main Game Loop:**

```
# Main game loop
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    # Initilizes all the sub modules inside of pygame.
    pygame.init()

    # Shortens what would be 2 window sizes into 1 variable
    window_size = window_width, window_height = 640,480
    # Takes the window size variable called display_size and makes the window
    game_display = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)
    # Sets the window/caption name/title
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    # Sets the game FPS(Frames Per Second)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60

    # block sprite group
    block_group = pygame.sprite.Group

    a_block = Block()
    a_block.set_position(window_width/2,window_height/2)

    block_group.add(a_block)

    # Draws the sprite group called block to the game_display
    block_group.draw(game_display)
```

Comment: `lock_group = pygame.sprite.Group()`

Comment: Well, I didn't even notice that thanks XD

Comment: Please mark as answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
lock_group = pygame.sprite.Group() # instantiate the class to create an object
```